# Finding m parameter value for which two functions are parallel

Tags: functions

I need to find the m parameter value for which two functions are parallel:

$$f(x) = 3 - (m - \sqrt{2})x - 3$$
$$g(x) = (\sqrt{2}m + 1)x + m$$

Given that the factor next to x has to be the same for those two functions, first I equate them, then I do some simple transformations:

$$-m + \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}m + 1$$
$$-m - \sqrt{2} m = 1 - \sqrt{2}$$
$$-m(1 - \sqrt{2}) = 1 - \sqrt{2}$$

Now, dividing both sides by 
$$(1 - \sqrt{2})$$

Then multiplying them by -1 will give a solution of:

$$m=-1$$

But the answer sheet says that:

$$m = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$$

Which is what I get at the one before the last step, so in this form:

$$-m(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$$

Obviously then I should divide by the common factor and multiply by -1, ultimately giving me the same result as I already got, right?
The question is - where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in the function $f(x)=\color{red}{3}-(m-\sqrt{2})x+\color{blue}{3}$.

Comment: $-m-\sqrt2m=-m(1+\sqrt2)$.

Comment: It's not  $-m(1-\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for $m$ results in $$\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2+1},$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{(\sqrt 2-1)^2}{2-1}=3-2\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: The coefficient is indeed $-m+\sqrt{2}$ because the coefficient of $x$ in $f(x)$ is $\color{red}{-}(m-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @AnuragA Ah, that's right. OP made a mistake in calculation, then.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on how you ended up with 2 - 1 in the denominator?

Comment: @MarekM. Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2-1}$$ and note that the denominator becomes $(\sqrt 2+1)(\sqrt 2-1)=(\sqrt 2)^2-1^2.$

Comment: Thank you very much!